# File concat error using ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am trying to concat two files using ffmpeg. I have a file input.txt where I have written

```
file "1.mpg"
file "2.mpg"
```

and the command i am using

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mpg
```

but i am keep getting this error impossible to open \1.mpg and input.txt: Invalid argument.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try ' instead of " around the filenames

Comment: solved a bit..but after the concatenation video isnt showing. But worked fine when I used .mp4 instead of .mpg

Comment: You should show the complete ffmpeg console output from your command and also show the output of `ffmpeg -i 1.mpg -i 2.mpg`. What player is the output not showing correctly in?

Comment: how this is not programming related?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mpg|2.mpg" -c copy output.mpg
```